# Visual Studio 2015 Diagnostic Tools Window doesn't show up

Tags: visual-studio-2015, diagnostic-tools

I'm able to show the diagnostic tools windows via Debug -> Windows -> Show Diagnostic Tool.

But that windows always disappears when starting / debugging the application.

What is going on?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I had the same.
The Diagnostic Tools window was closed.

While your application is started go to the menu:

Debug --> Windows --> Show Diagnostic Tools

I think Visual Studio has two different layouts during design time and run time.
So even it the window is showing in design time, it will not show when the project is running unless is selected during run time.

Comment: It shows up but under the meaningless 'Output' label, that contains a lot of other traces as well.

Comment: Another alternative is Ctrl + Alt + F2

Answer (score 6):

First of all check if Diagnostic Tools are enabled while debugging.

To check this go to **Tools->Options->Debugging** and check **Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging** checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my case **unchecking** the option "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" in Tools > Options > Debugging caused Diagnostic Tools and PerfTips appear. I have Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.